# Is there an adjective for someone who can withstand ridicule?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, connotation, synonyms

I've been searching both my mind and several thesauruses attempting to find the adjective that best describes this type of person.

The term "**thick-skinned**" is the closest to what I am trying to convey, but that carries the connotation that he/she is callous and does not care about others.

Is there a word that describes someone who is not easily offended -- able to withstand criticism, ridicule, or jokes made at his/her expense -- without also implying that the person is emotionally callous?

Comment: I would consider using your term, "thick-skinned". It fits well, and when used in context does not have the same connotation for me that you seem to apply to it.

Comment: Like @DigitalChris I'm not familiar with a connotation of callousness for the term **thick-skinned**. I consider it a perfect fit for your context, and tend to regard it as a compliment to people who can endure criticism or ridicule.

Comment: "self-assured" might work.

Comment: Do you think "Tolerant" would work?

Comment: cool? "free from excitement, anxiety, or excessive emotion"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[good sport](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+sport)***

> someone who can accept a loss in a competition or can accept being the butt of a joke.

It is used as a noun. The definition is related to being able to take a joke but it also covers accepting criticism with grace.

---

As an adjective, I would say ***[easygoing](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/easy-going).*** This would describe the type of person.

> relaxed in manner or attitude; inclined to be excessively tolerant

---

As a phrase, there is ***[have a broad back](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+broad+back)***:

> not be easily hurt by criticism
>
> *It helps to have a broad back in showbusiness.*

But this goes back to ***[thick-skinned](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/thick-skinned)***:

> not easily hurt by criticism, insult, etc.

As you said, thick-skinned has two meanings. One of the meaning is what you ask but the other one is what you want to avoid. It would depend on the context then.

Comment: I think this best conveys the personality type that I'm trying to describe. If only it were an adjective!

Comment: Added an adjective also. It is mentioned in a "[How to **take a joke**](http://www.wikihow.com/Take-a-Joke)" article as well.

Answer (score 5):

[Unflappable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Unflappable) can be used to  describe this kind of attitude:

> not easily perturbed or excited or upset; *marked by extreme calm and composure;* "hitherto imperturbable, he now showed signs of alarm"; "an imperturbable self-possession"; "unflappable in a crisis"

Comment: this word really fits! You can even use "impertubable" :)

Comment: I like unflappable, but maybe that's because I seem to encounter so many flappable people.

Comment: Unflappable is more akin to 'unwavering'. One can be unwavering through criticism, but that isn't the specific implication of the word.

Answer (score 4):

You could describe someone who magnanimously (rather than unfeelingly) endures offensive comments as ***[imperturbable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imperturbable)***, *[impervious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impervious) to criticism*, or *[undaunted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undaunted) by insult*. Related words include *[unflinching](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unflinching)* and *undismayed*.

If a verb phrase is appropriate in the context, you could also use *[hold one's head high](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+head+high)* to describe someone who remains composed and proud, in spite of insult or criticism.

> Despite the vitriolic insults, the dignified woman seemed *impervious to insult*.
>
> He *held his head high*, even during the personal attack.
>
> The politician was *imperturbable*, in spite of the constant attacks on his foreign policy.

Comment: Those are good phrases, but it would be great to find a single word that best fits the definition, if it exists.

Comment: @maxton I added some additional options, including single words and verb phrases.

Comment: a detailed germane answer.

Comment: @vickyace Thank you! I generally supply multiple options with subtle differences in connotation, so that the asker can (hopefully) find at least one that he/she thinks is applicable.

Answer (score 3):

**[Longanimous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/longanimous)** patient endurance of hardship, injuries, or offense; forbearance.

Answer (score 1):

There is the word [*Teflon*,](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Teflon) which has this as one of its meanings:

> [AS MODIFIER] Used to refer to someone able to withstand criticism or attack with no apparent effect

It is from the trademark name for the Dupont product described as:

> A tough synthetic resin made by polymerizing tetrafluoroethylene, used to coat nonstick cooking utensils and to make seals and bearings.

It is also a common nickname for politicians and public figures. See this Wikipedia entry: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teflon_(nickname)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teflon_%28nickname%29)

Comment: Although this is a good word to use, I believe that it refers more to the idea that criticism has no lasting effect on one's **reputation**, in relation to Teflon's non-sticking properties.

Answer (score 0):

try ["unaffected"](https://www.wordnik.com/words/unaffected)

> adj. Free from affectation; plain; simple; natural; real; sincere;
>   genuine

or ["imperviable"](https://www.wordnik.com/words/imperviable)

> adj. not admitting of passage or capable of being affected

or ["uninfluenced"](https://www.wordnik.com/words/uninfluenced)

> Not influenced; not persuaded or moved by others, or by foreign
>   considerations; not biased; acting freely

Comment: Cool, I've never heard "imperviable" before! It sounds like a blend between "impervious" and "impermeable".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you should use thick skinned because it can be used in any context.

Other words that can used here are "unabashed," which means not embarrassed, disconcerted, or ashamed. Look it up on Oxford or Merriam.

also try brazen, bashless and like synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

This may be going at it from the wrong direction,
but a person would be more able to withstand ridicule
if (s)he were [*confident*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/confident?s=t)
(or [*self-confident*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/self-confident?s=t)),
or, perhaps, [*emotionally secure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_security).

Another word that came to my mind was [*insensitive*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/insensitive?s=t);
i.e., the opposite of the somewhat pejorative meaning of
[*sensitive*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sensitive?&o=100074&s=t)
(i.e., implicitly, *over-sensitive*). 
But that suffers from the same problem as *thick-skinned*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [stoic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stoic#Adjective), specifically definitions 2 and 3. "Not affected by pain or distress." and "Not displaying any external signs of being affected by pain or distress."