# Any words to describe someone who ignores anyone 'mean' to them?

Tags: phrases

I'm looking for words to describe a person like Mma Ramotswe from No.1 Ladies Detective Agency for my blog - http://aroundtheworldinbooks.weebly.com/. Thanks to anyone who answers!

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/179013/is-there-an-adjective-for-someone-who-can-withstand-ridicule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common expression for letting other people's negative comments and behavior towards you "bounce off", is being ***"thick-skinned"*.**

Comment: Is aloof an appropriate word to use as well?

Comment: "Aloof" may be a trait your character also possesses, but it doesn't mean the same thing. For example; I am thick-skinned, (everyone who knows me, knows this) but I am also very approachable (not aloof, at all) - no one who is well acquainted with me seems to feel the slightest trepidation when letting me know how fat I've gotten.

Answer (score 0):

With proper context:

**being kryptonite** to negative comments

> SPIN - Sep 2006 - Page 96 Vol. 22, No. 9 - ‎Magazine
>
> Still, he finds it amusing that, when seated at the table **he is
>   kryptonite**, but when he has walked the floor, he has been stopped by
>   numerous men wanting information on how to break into the business.

_

> An unpublished 1940 story "The K-Metal from Krypton", by Superman
>   co-creator Jerry Siegel featured a prototype of kryptonite, a mineral
>   from the planet Krypton that drained Superman of his strength while
>   giving humans superhuman powers.[3]
>
> [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite)