# Adjective for someone who doesn't react when someone insults them?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What's a good adjective to describe someone who doesn't react when someone does something immature or insults them?

Comment: There are many reasons you might not react. For instance you could be an apathetic person or afraid of retaliation, but I guess that's not what you're thinking about. I think you should be clearer about why the person does not react.

Comment: Why don't they react? Are they frigid, catatonic, passive, holier-than-thou, dumb or just playing dumb?

Comment: Sounds like a Buddhist to me.

Comment: Too broad!  More context please.

Comment: A practicing Christian! Don

Comment: Is this a one-off reaction to a particular instance, or are you seeking to characterise the general behaviour of the person?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Is there an adjective for someone who can withstand ridicule?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/179013/191178) (or the other way around).

Answer (score 25):

I prefer [unflappable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unflappable), which means in the face of provocation one is usually [unfazed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfazed).

Comment: cool under pressure

Answer (score 17):

How about *stoic?*

> 1 *capitalized* : of, relating to, or resembling the Stoics or their doctrines
>
> 2 : not affected by or showing passion or feeling; especially: firmly restraining response to pain or distress

From [Merriam-Webster Online.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic)

Comment: Where did you get the quote? You should attribute your sources.

Comment: Sorry! I should know better. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 16):

To remain **impassive** (or *impassible*)

> Definition: revealing no emotion; expressionless, giving no sign of feeling.
>
> Example: she remained impassive as the officers informed her of her son's death

Comment: Keep in mind that the connotations of someone's being impassive do not quite match with OP's circumstance. I understand the incident to be something along the lines of name-calling or a childish prank. Impassivity is generally used more to indicate a general blankness, even coldness, rather than a positive attribute indicating resistance to nonsense. That's my feeling, anyway.

Answer (score 12):

There are many terms that spring to mind, but the first for me was [thick-skinned](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thick-skinned).

Answer (score 8):

I think the word you need is ***phlegmatic***.

The OED lists etymology, and multiple senses - nounal and adjectival. Perhaps the one most relevant to the question is adjectival sense 2.

> 2. Having, showing, or characteristic of the temperament formerly believed to result from a predominance of phlegm among the bodily
>      humours; not easily excited to feeling or action; stolidly calm,
>      self-possessed, imperturbable; (with pejorative connotation) sluggish,
>      apathetic, lacking enthusiasm.

The various senses have examples from as early as the 14th century. But here are just three recent ones from sense 2.

> 1888   F. Hume Madame Midas i. iv. 33   Selina resumed her knitting in
>   a most phlegmatic manner.
>
> 1915   W. S. Maugham Of Human Bondage xxx. 130   No sign of
>   astonishment appeared on Emil's phlegmatic face.
>
> 1991   Sunday Mail Mag. (Brisbane)  1 Dec. 12/2   She has the robust
>   air of a true countrywoman, phlegmatic, pragmatic, aware that sooner
>   or later, nature, or life, will kick you in the teeth.

Comment: This was the word I thought of first.  I would upvote if you added some supporting information.

Answer (score 7):

How about Unaffected or
Unperturbed?

Answer (score 4):

blasé

/bläˈzā/ adjective 
unimpressed or indifferent to something because one has experienced or seen it so often before.

Example: He was blasé about being down voted.

Comment: Et tu, Brute?  Et tu, Brute!

Answer (score 4):

You could be indifferent; just don't care.

Answer (score 4):

Could this person be a perfect personification, of pluterperfect imperturbability?  So in a word, imperturbable.

Of course, that answer assumes you wish to describe a person who maintains a regular expression in the face of adversity.  So my reply presumes the response is part of a pattern matching the expected behaviour of your character.  If, however, your narrative has this reaction as an isolated incident, then the suggestion of Shark Trager, may be more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In such a generic situation as that, I would just say mature.

She was perfectly mature in the face of her younger brother's taunting. She didn't even bat an eye.

More casually, grown up.

Comment: This sounds like you're describing the person's character, not their reaction  to being insulted. Are you saying that mature people never react to any gratuitous or childish insult? Moreover, not all insults are infantile.

Comment: In regards to "does something immature or insults them" from the OP, I'm interpreting what we have to work with as general peevish childishness. Naturally, there are serious insults that require serious responses. "Mature" is often used situationally, not just to describe character, e.g. "she was so mature about that!" "Way to be mature." That's all I mean by it.

Comment: The OP seems well aware of the term *immature*, it is present in the actual question; I think the OP is looking for a different or more specific term, but what exactly, is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

nonplussed

```
North American informal
(of a person) not disconcerted; unperturbed.
```

Comment: More generally "nonplussed" is used in the sense of "WTF?" The usage you refer to is a recent development and not in the least standard English.  source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nonplussed

Answer (score 2):

They're like [**Teflon**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/teflon)

Or it [the insult] is like

> water off a duck's back

Answer (score 2):

In the case of an immature act or insult, I suggest - confident.
A person with confidence knows they are above the insult or immature act and will not allow it to steer them off course.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Can you explain a bit more, or back up your suggestion with a relevant definition or cited source? (It's always a good idea to include good quality references to support your answers.)

Comment: I don't think is a good answer. "Confident" might explain *why* they don't react, but it isn't an adjective describing that they don't react.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't react when you should, then you are 'numb' or 'dead' or a 'potato'.
If you're good at controlling yourself in a good way, then you are 'stoic'.
If you self-control like a robot, or get no feelings to control, then you are 'stone-faced', 'affectless', or a 'robot'.

And so many other adjectives ...